# MySQL Join three table if one table no record

Tags: mysql, select, join

```
$numQuery1 = "
SELECT d.*
     , r.*
     , AVG(c.on_time)+AVG(c.friendly)+AVG(c.language_skills)+AVG(c.professional) ranking
  FROM comment c
  LEFT 
  JOIN driver d
    ON d.userid = c.driver_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN driver_rental r
    ON r.email = d.email 
 WHERE 
     ( 
       $driver_rental IS NOT NULL 
   AND $driver_rental != ''
   AND car_type_1 >= $_SESSION[car_type_1] 
     )
    OR car_type_2>=$_SESSION[car_type_1]);
";
```

if the comment table have no driver_id record, the result is null, can I ignore comment table but in select statement cannot without it?

Comment: Presumably car_type_1 comes from the driver rental table? (It's really useful if you make this kind of thing explicit in your query)

Answer (score 0):

```
$numQuery1 = "SELECT driver.*, driver_rental.*, avg(comment.on_time)+avg(comment.friendly)+avg(comment.language_skills)+avg(comment.professional) as ranking
    FROM comment
    LEFT JOIN driver
    ON
    driver.userid = comment.driver_id
    RIGHT JOIN driver_rental
    ON
    driver.email = driver_rental.email
    WHERE
    ($driver_rental IS NOT NULL AND $driver_rental != '') AND (car_type_1>=$_SESSION[car_type_1] OR car_type_2>=$_SESSION[car_type_1])";
```

The idea is to not stress on driver table in either join. SO instead of second left join use right join with driver_rental

Comment: in my case, driver.userid = comment.driver_id is no record, but the search result want to include comment table.

Comment: Thats why left join has been used so that if there are no records in driver table, still all the records from comment table will be used. But use second join should not be left but right join.

Comment: Erm, nobody uses RIGHT JOIN. Can you solve this another way?